# Python 3 Battle simulation

Tags: loops, random

I am new to Python and am trying to build a battle simulation program.  I am stuck with having my random generated numbers re-generate while in the while loop.  The program will generate a random number once and use that number through the program for each loop until the program ends.  Here is the program:

```
import time
from Weapon import wepn
from Axe import Axe
from Player import Player
from Enemy import Enmy
import random

big_axe = Axe(random.randint(12, 40))

Excalibur = wepn(random.randint(10, 35))

Orc = Enmy(100, random.randint(20, 40))

Warrior = Player(100, random.randint(10, 25), 15)

potion = 25

potion_num = 4

orc_atk = random.randint(1, 2)


        if orc_atk == 1:
           print("You get hit and take " + str(Orc.damage - Warrior.armor) + " damage.\nYou have " + str(Warrior.player_hp - (Orc.damage - Warrior.armor)) + "HP left!")
        Warrior.player_hp -= (Orc.damage - Warrior.armor)
       if orc_atk == 2:
           print("You dodge the Orc attack!")

while Orc.enemy_hp > 0 and Warrior.player_hp > 0:
time.sleep(1.5)
choice = input("\nThe Orc charges at you, what do you do?\nA) Use Sword\nB) Use Axe \nC) Use Potion\n")
if choice == "a":
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\nYou attack the orc with your swift sword")
    print("The Orc is hit, it has " + str(Orc.enemy_hp - Excalibur.damage) + "HP left!")
    Orc.enemy_hp -= Excalibur.damage
    print("The orc attacks you")
    if orc_atk == 1:
        print("You get hit and take " + str(Orc.damage - Warrior.armor) + " damage.\nYou have " + str(Warrior.player_hp - (Orc.damage - Warrior.armor)) + "HP left!")
        Warrior.player_hp -= (Orc.damage - Warrior.armor)
    if orc_atk == 2:
        print("You dodge the Orc attack!")
if choice == "b":
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\nYou swing your mighty axe and hit the Orc!")
    print("The Orc takes " + str(big_axe.damage) + " damage, the Orc has " + str(Orc.enemy_hp - big_axe.damage) + " HP left!")
    Orc.enemy_hp -= big_axe.damage
    if orc_atk == 1:
        print("You get hit and take " + str(Orc.damage - Warrior.armor) + " damage.\nYou have " + str(Warrior.player_hp - (Orc.damage - Warrior.armor)) + "HP left!")
        Warrior.player_hp -= (Orc.damage - Warrior.armor)
    if orc_atk == 2:
        print("You dodge the Orc attack!")
if choice == "c":
    if potion_num > 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("You use a potion.\nYour HP is now " + str(Warrior.player_hp + potion))
        potion_num -= 1
        print("You have " + str(potion_num) + " potion(s) left.")
        Warrior.player_hp += potion
    if potion_num == 0:
        print("You are out of potions.")
if Enmy.is_alive(Orc):
    print("The Orc still lives")
if not Player.still_fighting(Warrior):
    print("You were defeated!")
if not Enmy.is_alive(Orc):
    print("You defeated the Orc!")
```

Comment: What loop? There are no loops in this code. Please show all of the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was having a hard time putting all the code in the comment.

Comment: while Orc.enemy_hp > 0 and Warrior.player_hp > 0:

Comment: Put the code *in the question*, that's what it's for.

Comment: code is now in the question.

Comment: Doesn't look like your loop is indented properly--that's not just for style, it matters in Python.

Comment: Minor bit of code review... if you're happy to have things like `Player`, why are you creating things with weird abbreviations like `Enmy`?

Comment: I saw it on another game someone else made, no other reason.  Kinda just copied the abbreviations of the code I used.  Just out of curiosity, does the while loop in my code need to be indented if it is the "start" of my program?  Just curious, still learning.  The issue I am having with the program is that at the orc_atk if statement it will pick a random number once then keep that number until the program is finished.  Thank you for your feed back.